# Hierarchical style query has appalling performance in Cypher.. Should I use Traverser API?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My cypher query is as follows ( I am looking to find out users that have bought in sectors)

```
START n=node:sectors('SECTOR_ID:65, SECTOR_ID:66 ...') // 20 sectors  
MATCH (n)-[:HAS_DOMAIN]->(dom)-[:HAS_CAT]->(cat)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(prod)-[:BOUGHT_BY]->(user)
RETURN n.sector_name, COUNT(user), COLLECT(DISTINCT(product.name)), ... etc.
```

I find that because on every traversal the number of paths rises exponentially,
the final query has a result time of 25 seconds.
So, i.e. if a sector has 50 domains, each domain has 1000 categories and each category
has 250K++ products.

It seems to me this is the 'supernode problem'... or there are just too many paths!

Should I be using the Traverser API?
Should I try to model my data in a different way?

Any ideas welcome!

Neo4j 1.8.3, Linux

Thanks!

Comment: Does it make any difference if you break the query in two with `WITH`? I don't think I've ever queried with such an open-ended pattern, but my sense would be to profile memory usage and compare with the same query broken, something like `...->(cat) WITH cat MATCH...`, as I would expect it to force complete matching the first half of the pattern before continuing with the rest. Fuzzy hunch caveat emptor.

Comment: There could be a number of things going on here - Firstly, your doing a ton of lookups on Sectors - each of these could take ~1sec.

Have you tried searching back from the Users? All users who Purchased something and navigate back to the sectors based on the relationships that exist?

Comment: @Mike No, the lookup takes just a few millis (through Lucene).
The costs start becoming large when the paths multiply.
No, I cannot start from the users, I want to get aggregate statistics on users per sector.

Comment: @jjaderberg . I can see how that will help, since the same products can belong into different categories. I will try it out and report

Comment: If you have unnecessary duplicates you might also try filtering these earlier. For instance, applying `DISTINCT(product)` earlier might avoid matching the same set of users from a product many times.

Comment: @jjaderberg 
Indeed, doing a WITH DISTINCT on each pass helps a lot... However! I need to be collecting statistics along the way, as: in how many different domains/categories has the user bought into, etc.
Plus I want to do order and paging, which would be nice to do in the db with SKIP and LIMIT... 
So, then it becomes slow again... 
I think one approach would be to split it and then collate the results, with the minus that the whole resultset will be drawn in memory.
Another one would be to try the Traverser API, which I have not attempted yet.

Comment: Since you are open to modeling your data in a different way, consider aggregating as you insert data. Example of a date based one is: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html

With this you might do it at the prodcut level by having a node that is the sum of the [:BOUGHT_BY] relationships, and update it each time.

Also, if you don't want to do that, you might not actually have to get the User node since you aren't doing anything to to the user.  It might save one step if you just count the number of BOUGHT_BY relationships since that will give you the same count.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is actually memory, as you try to load all paths. If it is statistics you want, you will almost certainly be better off with the Traverser API so that you can control how nodes are loaded/aggregated.

If you want to stick to Cypher, it may help to break each sector out to it's own query so that they can be better run in parallel. If you have complete control of the read/write of the database, then another option it to create ledger nodes that you can update when reading/writing. That way, you don't need to know all paths, just how this one change affects the statistics. You can also create direct relationships from sector to interesting nodes and just collect the information you want into a single element like

```
(sector)-[:HAS_CAT]->(cat)
WITH sector, collect(cat.name) as Categories
```

That way, with each match, you can consolidate back to your original number of columns.